# cause of the interval it is divergent,is it measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

If a function is unlimited in the interval, so divergent. Is this function measurable or integrable?
Thanks for your help

Comment: ...what? ${}{}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ for $x \in(0,1)$. Since $f$ is continuous, $f$ is measurable. An easy computation gives

$\int_0^1 f(x)  dx=2$. Hence $f$ is Riemann- integrable on $(0,1)$, and therefore Lebesgue-integrable on $(0,1)$, since $f>0$.

Comment: I got it. My mistake